# Smallest ordinal modelling $\aleph_1$?

Tags: set-theory, model-theory, foundations, ordinal-numbers

Let $X_1$ be the class of all ordinals $\alpha$ such that there exists a transitive model $M$ of ZF(C) such that $M$ thinks that $\alpha$ is $\aleph_1$.

Every class of ordinals has a minimum element (because ordinals are well-ordered), so let $\alpha_1$ be the smallest ordinal in $X_1$.

So, I have 2 questions:

> 1. Is the class $X_1$ actually well-defined?
> 2. If it is well-defined, what can we determine about the actual value of $\alpha_1$?

We could also ask the same question for $\aleph_\beta$ (for any ordinal $\beta$) instead of $\aleph_1$, which I'd also be interested in.

---

My thoughts:

There are two points I think to verify that $X_1$ is well-defined. The first is that "is a transitive model of ZF(C)" is definable in the language of ZF(C), and the second is that "$M$ thinks $\alpha$ is $\aleph_1$" needs to be definable.

Being transitive is definable, so really, the first part reduces to whether "being a model of ZF(C)" is definable. I'm a little unsure of whether or not it is, because ZFC is not finitely axiomatizable, but NBG is, which makes me think the idea behind this question might still be salvageable even if it's not definable in ZF(C).

As for that "$M$ thinks $\alpha$ is $\aleph_1$" is definable, it seems very true, because countability is definable, and then "every ordinal less than $\alpha$ is countable, but $\alpha$ is not countable", which should definitely be definable.

So, that means, that part 2 makes sense to talk about. We know that (at least for small enough $\beta$), $\alpha_\beta$ must be countable, because countable models of ZF(C) exist (by Lowenheim Skolem), which is already interesting. I suspect they are all fairly big countable ordinals, almost certainly larger than $\omega_1^{CK}$.

Comment: If there is a transitive model of ZFC then there is a minimal one. You're looking for the $\omega_1$ of that minimal transitive model. But there may not be a transitive model of ZFC. In particular, in the minimal transitive model there is no transitive model of ZFC.

Comment: Definability of the notion "the $\aleph_1$ of some transitive model of ZFC" is not a problem, but, as Francois pointed out, existence of a transitive model of ZFC is an assumption that goes beyond ZFC. Under this assumption, your $\alpha_1$ exists, and it's a countable ordinal, but it's way bigger than $\omega_1^{CK}$. (In fact, the  $\omega_1^{CK}$ of any transitive model of ZF is the same as the genuine  $\omega_1^{CK}$.)

Comment: Ok, so then for the purposes of this question, it is assumed that there is a transitive model of ZFC. So, $\alpha_1$ exists. Then the question is what is $\alpha_1$ or $\alpha_\beta$ more generally. Can we know what it is? Can we get an upper bound on it at all? It seems to me that any ordinal which is definable and provably countable is a lower bound. So does that mean that $\alpha_1$ is the smallest ordinal such that no definable ordinal larger than it is provably countable? Or can we prove that even that isn't big enough to be $\omega_1$ in the minimal transitive model?

Comment: If $\alpha_1$ exists, then it's definable; in fact you've defined it, namely as "the first ordinal that is uncountable in some transitive model of ZF". Perhaps you intended "definable" to refer to some more restricted language or to definability in some particular model; but if so then you need to say what  language or model you intend. (Note that lots of bigger countable ordinals are definable too, like $\alpha_{17}$.)

Comment: I know $\alpha_1$ is definable... I defined it :P. I tried to clarify by saying "provably countable"... meaning that ZF(C) proves that the given definition of the ordinal is countable. But now I realize that that was incredibly stupid because ZF(C) proves that the above definition of $\alpha_1$ is countable.

Comment: @DylanPizzo Or rather, ZFC + "ZFC has a transitive model" defines $\alpha_1$ and proves it's countable. :0)

Comment: By the way, I feel it's appropriate to add that letting $\theta$ be the least ordinal so that $L_\theta\models\text{ZFC}$ (which exists assuming any transitive model exists), your $\alpha_1$ is $\omega_1^{L_\theta}$. Indeed, this ordinal is quite large but note that $\theta$ itself must be larger.

Comment: @Keith of course $\theta$ would be bigger. It would be larger than $\alpha_\beta$ for every ordinal $\beta$. I would suspect that the limit of these ordinals would be the smallest ordinal $\gamma$ such that $V_\gamma$ is a model of ZF(C). I don't know how $\gamma$ relates to $\theta$, but I would guess that they're equal, since $L_\theta$ is a transitive model, right?

Comment: @DylanPizzo Nope, the least such $\gamma$ is uncountable (a cardinal, in fact, and not known to be consistent with ZFC) but $\theta$ is countable

Comment: "Being a model of ZFC" is definable since ZFC is a recursive theory, so we could construct some $\Sigma_1^0$ predicate $\textrm{isZFCAxiom}(e)$ for $e$ a Godel-coding of a formula in the language of ZFC. Then I believe we can formalize "$M$ is a model of ZFC" by $\forall(e\in\mathbb N)(\textrm{isZFCAxiom}(e)\rightarrow M\vDash e)$ using some formalization of $\vDash$ for Godel-codes, such as the one in this set of notes ("Models of Set Theory I") by Koepke: http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/ag/logik/teaching/2017SS/Models%20Of%20Set%20Theory%201/Aktuelles_Skript_Models.pdf#page=15.

Comment: Since ZFC is consistent with V=L, many results here also apply: http://cantorsattic.info/Heights_of_models

Comment: I think it would be more interesting to ask about ordinals $\alpha$ which some transitive set $M$ believes is the smallest uncountable ordinal, where $M$ is assumed to be a model of a very minimal subset of ZFC so that ordinals can be defined and compared (so that “smallest uncountable ordinal” has an unambiguous meaning), not all of ZFC.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen On that note, the $\omega_1$ of the minimal transitive model of $\mathsf{KP}$ + "$\omega_1$ exists" has a definability-theoretic characterization [due to Schlutzenberg](https://mathoverflow.net/a/381041/8133).

Answer (score 6):

About well-definedness of $X_1$, "being a model of ZFC" is definable since ZFC is a recursive theory, so we could construct some $\Sigma_1^0$ predicate $\textrm{isZFCAxiom}(e)$ for $e$ a Godel-coding of a formula in the language of ZFC. Then I believe we can formalize "$M$ is a model of ZFC" by $\forall(e\in\mathbb N)(\textrm{isZFCAxiom}(e)\rightarrow M\vDash e)$ using some formalization of $\vDash$ for Godel-codes (for an explicit example, [this set of notes "Models of Set Theory I" by Koepke](http://cantorsattic.info/Heights_of_models)).

---

Bounding $\alpha_1$: The following paragraph is an argument I heard from [another MathOverflow user](https://mathoverflow.net/users/30186/) by personal communication.

To avoid considering arbitrary transitive models, for any transitive $M$ where $(M,\in)\vDash\textrm{ZF}$ we have $L^M\subseteq M$ and $(L^M,\in)\vDash\textrm{ZF}$. These models $L^M$ must be of the form $L_\xi$ (or $(L_\xi)^V$) for some ordinal $\xi$, and we have $\aleph_1^{(L^M)}\leq\aleph_1^M$, so without loss of minimality we can just consider the ordinals $\aleph_1^{L_\xi}$ where $(L_\xi,\in)\vDash\textrm{ZF}$. Also, to ensure we're bounding $\alpha_1$ and not just the $\aleph_1$ of the minimal model, we can show that $\gamma<\delta$ implies $\aleph_1^{L_\gamma}\leq\aleph_1^{L_\delta}$, since any bijection $\omega\rightarrow \aleph_1^{L_\delta}$ that's a member of $L_\gamma$ must also be a member of $L_\delta$. So the $\aleph_1$ of the minimal model of ZF is indeed $\alpha_1$.

From here on let $\xi$ be least such that $L_\xi\vDash\textrm{ZF}$. Each $L_\xi$ modeling ZF is admissible, so we can apply Theorem 10.2 of Arai's "[A sneak preview of proof theory of ordinals](https://arxiv.org/abs/1102.0596v1)", stating admissible $L_\xi$ satisfying "$\alpha$ is a cardinal $>\rho$" for some $\rho<\xi$ must have $L_\xi\cap\mathcal P(\omega)=L_\alpha\cap\mathcal P(\rho)$. Using some results from §4 of Marek and Srebrny's thesis "[Gaps in the constructible universe](https://philpapers.org/rec/MARGIT-4)" we obtain some weak lower bounds on $\alpha$: it's larger than the ordinal of ramified analysis $\beta_0$, and larger than the ordinal $\xi$ starting a gap of length $\beta^\beta$ of corollary 4.12. For the bonus question on $\aleph_n^M$, similar results apply when $\rho>\omega$, using the analogous notions of $\rho$-gaps (i.e. gaps in $L_\bullet\cap\mathcal P(\rho)$) introduced in §7.

---

Strengthening the bounds: Since we know the gap starts at $\alpha_1$ and ends at $\xi$, we can strengthen this bound by showing that the gap is long, e.g. contains many admissibles: let $\sigma_0$ be the $\Pi_3$ formula expressing "the universe is an admissible set" from Richter and Aczel's ["Inductive Definitions and Reflecting Properties of Admissible Ordinals"](https://www.duo.uio.no/handle/10852/44063). Working in $L_\xi$, ZF proves $\forall\rho((\rho\textrm{ is a cardinal }>\omega)\rightarrow(\sigma_0)^{L_\rho})$, we assumed ZF is sound by assuming ZF has a transitive model, so $L_\rho$ satisfies this sentence. Since each relativization $(\sigma_1)^{L_\rho}$ is $\Delta_0$, each one is absolute and therefore true in $V$, so each $L_\rho$-cardinal, while not really a cardinal, is really admissible. So we get many admissibles (e.g. $\aleph_2^{L_\xi}$,  $\aleph_\omega^{L_\xi}$,  $\aleph_{\omega_1^{L_\xi}+\varepsilon_0^{234}}^{L_\xi}$) between the start and end points of the gap.

We can repeat this section but based on stronger properties of $L_\rho$-cardinals to improve this further. For instance Barwise's *Admissible Sets and Structures* has an exercise to show each $L_\rho$-cardinal $>\omega$ must be $\rho$-stable for admissible $\rho$, from which we can show each aforementioned $L_\rho$-cardinal in our gap is inaccessibly-stable. (However we need to be careful about showing these properties are absolute w.r.t. $V$)